# does gaia.com break the law?

Tags: trademark, liability, fraud

Gaia.com is pushing conspiracy theories about reincarnation and aliens which would hopefully be fake to a normal folk robbed by a gaia.com ad, this is another way of making money using lies, is this against the law?

Comment: How can someone be "robbed" by viewing an online advert, which is basically the same as a roadside billboard?

Comment: How is the site robbing people? What law do you think they are breaking? Username does not check out.

Comment: Wait. That can only be misinformation if it contradicts proven facts about aliens and the afterlife.  **What are those facts, exactly?**

Comment: robbing them from truth.

Comment: i was clearly using a metaphor, and because of that I got 2 downvotes

Comment: If it helps, I downvoted because this question reads more like a rant. Though being deliberately unclear would also earn a downvote. Alas, I have but one downvote to give.

Comment: Truth is not a tangible item, which is needed for **robbery**

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the USA, since that's where they appear to be located.

Spreading misinformation is not illegal- it is protected by the first amendment. There are exceptions but I can't see how any would apply here. You haven't mentioned any that you think apply.

If some of the videos on the site guaranteed results or made medical claims, maybe that could be considered false advertising. However, I see no evidence of this. Users are advertised that paying for access to a bunch of hocum videos will get them access to a bunch of snake oil and this appears to be the case.

Comment: False advertisement or fraud, but not robbery.